# ERA5 reference time zone

Tags: weather, climate

I am using temperature information from [ERA5](https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/datasets/reanalysis-datasets/era5) reanalysis hourly data on a single level, and I am confused about time reference.

If I download global temperature data for a specific day and time (for example, 2000-08-08 07:00) is this UTC or is it adjusted to the local time of each point of the grid? In other words, will I be looking for 07:00 in the US and also for 07:00 in Germany? Or they are referred to UTC, and in the US I will be looking for nighttime temperature while in Germany it will already be morning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTC ([Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) is the only way that makes sense for a global dataset. Using local timezones would be an absolute nightmare for exactly this reason.

I found several references to UTC in the [ERA5 data documentation](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5+data+documentation).

- > **'time' in analyses**
  >   Each analysis has a validity time, i.e. the time the data values refer to (not the time when the analysis was computed). All validity times are in hours UTC. [source](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=85402030#ERA5terminology:analysisandforecast;timeandsteps;instantaneousandaccumulatedandmeanratesandmin/maxparameters-'time'inanalyses)
- > **'time' in forecasts**
  >   Each forecast starts with the atmospheric conditions at a specific 'initialization time'. In ERA5 a new forecast is computed twice a day, with initialization times of 06:00 and 18:00 UTC. In the ERA5 data archive, for forecasts, 'time' (and date) refers to the initialization time.

I didn't anything that explicitly says they used UTC throughout, but the documentation is hundreds of pages long and I didn't read it word-for-word. If anyone manages to find specific confirmation whether all the times in this dataset are in UTC, please provide a direct link.